# upgrading from PHP 7.0 to PHP 8.0

Tags: php, php-7.4, php-8

There is a issue in my all projects. It was working fine and perfect in PHP 7.0 but in PHP 8.0 it is showing error.  In   I was creating POST and GET variables like this (without single quote):

```
1) $_POST[dob]
2) $_GET[id]
3) INSERT INTO company VALUES($_POST[dob],$_GET[id])
```

For sessions, GET mehtod, Cookies everywhere i was creating variable without single quote. Now its deprecated in php 8.0

Is there any shortcut method / Any funtions or get rid of this issue?

Comment: No, add quotes. Actually, you're code throws _"Undefined constant"_ errors. And you should learn to use [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60496/9193372).

Comment: Your text mentions PHP 7.0, but your tags mention 7.4. This is an important difference, because in 7.0 this would only have given you a Notice (the manual had a whole section explaining why it was wrong, but the Notice was easily ignored); from 7.2 onwards, this gave a Warning, with a clear message that it was going to become an error soon (that was the stage it was "deprecated", which is a warning of a _future_ change); in 8.0, it has become an error (it's not just deprecated any more, it's gone, and it's not coming back).

Answer (score 2):

From the [PHP 8 migration guide section on backward incompatible changes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php), that feature was removed:

> Attempting to access unqualified constants which are undefined. Previously, unqualified constant accesses resulted in a warning and were interpreted as strings.

The “trick” you were using was still resulting in a warning which you were just ignoring. There is no fix except not upgrading or using quotes.